# DIV just shows up when post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem when i hide DIV tag in client side and then click submit to postback the data
to server side .After that ,The DIV just show up .how to fix this

Comment: My guess is that you hide it with javascript and you expect to remember that by him self after the post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some basics trying to describe what you should do:

You must send some data to the server side, for example by using a hidden field, and on the server side (in code behind) on postback check for that data. If data is present do `panel.Visible = false` (if the div is a component named panel).

If you don't do something like this the page will only be output like it is in the aspx file. The page has no notion that the div was hidden in the borwser after the last time the page was sent to the browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Server seem to remember the state of the DIV .I tried Enableviewstate = "false" but it did not work .Ur solution works fine for be but this solution seem to be weird.Thank for help

Comment: This is just how it works in asp.net. Asp.net is designed around postbacks and that you do you manipulation of objects in the page in the your code behind, not with javascript. When the page is used in the browser it is in the "browser world". When the page is processed on the server it is in the "server world". To send state between the two "worlds" you need to use techinques like this. That is why asp.net would not be my choice if I were to create a new application that was supposed to do many things with javascript. I would use MVC where it is at least a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yes the server will remember the state of the DIV. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I use script manager to keep the div hiding Here is my code

```
    Dim javastr As String = "$('#detail_div').hide();alert('New data is added successfully');"
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Me.GetType(), "persistence", javastr, True)
```

Thank for everyone and every comment.
It is time to learn MVC.